# Where can I storage a local database?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I want to create a website where the users can have their own database. An example:
- An user will receive some data from HTTP POST and I want to storage all the information into a local database to access to it. For example, the URL that the user has visited in the last month.

I know that the best option will be to create a database in my server and put each user in it, but it will be very long database and the information between users is not shared, therefore it will be more secure using a local database, but I don´t know if that can be done.

My project is about ESP8266 and uploading data to a server, so this can be done using a microcontroller instead the computer. I have seen the raspberry to use it as a server and storage there the database, but it is so expensive. Can be done using another board as Arduino, Texas Instruments, etc...

The main aim is to create a main hub to storage all the values received from the ESP8266 and then share over internet, but I don´t know how to build a hub where I can store a database inside and a HTML website to show the values. Any ideas? I would like to avoid a computer to do it.

I think in something for less than 10 GBP, because I bought and Arduino and Ethernet shield for 5 GBP both, fake version, but useful for my project

Comment: You want a database but to avoid using a computer? I sense you will have problems with that.

Comment: Yes, for example can be used raspberry. And for Ardingly I know that can be done a HTML page host using ethernet shield, but I'm not sure if can be done a proper server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Sparkfun data project:

https://data.sparkfun.com/

they build an open source tool called `phant` (https://github.com/sparkfun/phant) that you use to host on your own or use their free version online

Comment: Phant is No Longer in Operation

Unfortunately Phant, our data-streaming service, is no longer in service and has been discontinued. The system has reached capacity and, like a less-adventurous Cassini, has plunged conclusively into a fiery and permanent retirement. There are several other maker-friendly, data-streaming services and/or IoT platforms available as alternatives. The three we recommend are Blynk, ThingSpeak, and Cayenne. You can read our blog post on the topic for an overview and helpful links for each platform.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you want a 'mini' database for your ESP8266, without the need to connect to the internet.

One way I can think of is that you could use your ESP8266 flash memory to store the database. Use SPIFFS with, say, 1 MBytes flash size, leaving 3 MBytes for your actual program (assuming the ESP8266 has 4 MB flash memory). More than 20 thousand record files for 50 bytes each.

But you'll need to write your own create, read, update, delete (CRUD) function to handle the files.

If someone has already written such functions, that would be useful to share here.